# Have these two Taylor Series been solved incorrectly?

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

$1).$ Find the Taylor Series of $f(x)= e^{-2x-3}$ about $a = 0$.

So there is the known Taylor Series for $f(x) = e^{x}$

$f(x) = e^{x} = 1 + \frac{x^{1}}{1!} + \frac{x^{2}}{2!} + \frac{x^{3}}{3!} + \frac{x^{4}}{4!} + ….$

So I take the derivatives of $e^{x}$ up to the $4th$.

$f^{0}(0) = e^{-2(0)-3} = e^{-3}$
$f^{1}(0) = e^{-2x-3}(-2^{1}) = e^{-3}(-2) = 1*e^{-3}(-2)$
$f^{2}(0) = e^{-2x-3}(-2^{2}) = e^{-2(0)-3}(-2^{2}) = 1*e^{-3}(-2)^{2}$
$f^{3}(0) = e^{-2x-3}(-2^{3}) = e^{-2(0)-3}(-2^{3}) = 1*e^{-3}(-2)^{3}$
$f^{4}(0) = e^{-2x-3}(-2^{4}) = e^{-2(0)-3}(-2^{4}) = 1*e^{-3}(-2)^{4}$

Thus, the Taylor Series is:
$e^{-2x-3} = e^{-3} + \frac{e^{3}(-2)}{1!} + \frac{e^{-3}(-2)^{2}}{2!} + \frac{e^{-3}(-2)^{2}}{3!} + \frac{e^{-3}(-2)^{2}}{4!} + ….$

$2).$ Find the Taylor Series of $f(x) = ln(x)$ about $a = 2$
No known Taylor Series for $f(x)=ln(x)$
So, start taking derivatives:

$f^{0}(2) = ln(2) = ln(2)$

$f^{1}(2) = \frac{1}{x} = \frac{1}{2}$

$f^{2}(2) = \frac{-1}{x^{2}} = \frac{-1}{4}$

$f^{3}(2) = \frac{2}{x^{3}} = \frac{2}{8} = \frac{1}{4}$

$f^{4}(2) = \frac{-6}{x^{4}} = \frac{-6}{16} = \frac{-3}{8}$

Thus, the Taylor Series ln(x) about a=2:
$ln(x) = ln(2) + \frac{1}{2}*(x-2) + \frac{\frac{-1}{4}} {2!}*(x - 2)^{2} + \frac{\frac{-1}{4}}{3!}*(x - 2)^{3} + \frac{\frac{-1}{4}}{4!}*(x - 2)^{4} +$

Thank you

Comment: There should be $x$s in your series for $e{-2x-3}$.

Comment: Your purported series for $\ln x$ looks more like an exponential than a logarithmic function.

Answer (score 0):

If they want a Taylor Series, you should find all infinite derivatives, not just 4. How do you do that? 2 ways:

a. Find and prove a closed formula for the n'th derivative.

b. Use another Taylor series that we are familiar with.

Let's start with the first question. Maybe the Taylor series of $e^x$ can be helpful, lets try:

$$ e^x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!} \Rightarrow e^{2x-3} = e^{-3} \cdot e^{2x} = e^{-3} \cdot \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(2x)^n}{n!} $$
$$ e^{2x-3} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{e^{-3} \cdot 2^n}{n!} x^n $$

Hurrah, that helped!

Try something similar (but maybe a bit more tricky) for the other series, good luck!

Comment: Just trying to make the connection between how you took the known $$e^{x}$$ summation notation and turned it into $$ e^{2x-3} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{e^{-3} \cdot 2^n}{n!} x^n $$ some algebra step or something I am not getting.

Comment: where did you lose me?